# .setLayoutX() not affecting position in FlowPane

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

For some reason or another `textExampleTwo.setLayoutX(40)` does not actually result in the `Text` moving at all to the right. Is this a bug or have I missed something important here?

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

    FlowPane flowPane = new FlowPane();
    flowPane.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);

    Text textExampleOne = new Text("An example - 1");

    Text textExampleTwo = new Text("An example - 2");
    textExampleTwo.setLayoutX(40.0);

    flowPane.getChildren().addAll(textExampleOne, textExampleTwo);

    Scene applicationScene = new Scene(flowPane);
    stage.setHeight(400.0);
    stage.setWidth(400.0);
    stage.setScene(applicationScene);
    stage.show();
}
```

[image: An image of the application (Note that they are on the same X level)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed something important here:

Many `Pane`s including `FlowPane` determine the position of their children on their own. For positioning the `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties are used. If you assign a new value to one of them and the `Node` is a child of a layout that positions it's children itself, this just leads to the position to be changed back during the next layout pass.

The exception to this are `Node`s with the `managed` property set to `false`. This leads to **neither** `layoutX` **nor** `layoutY` being assigned however.

In your case you seem to want a combination of the two.

In this case the desired effect can be achieved by setting a margin.

```
// set all insets except the left one to 0
FlowPane.setMargin(textExampleOne, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 40));
```

Note however that this does not set the x position to `40`, but it keeps a space of size 40 at the left of the `Node`. If you add enough children before this node to move it to the second column, this spacing would be used to calculate the distance to the beginning of the column.

Comment: ah, thanks for the help! There is one more thing I would like to ask though, can you do this for a Pane as well?